# I can't create new sale.order.line using .create(vals) in odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I can't create new `sale.order.line` using `.create(vals)` in `sale.order.line` model, and it kept giving me this error :

```py
  File "c:\users\enablr02\documents\addons\usm-backend-odoo\usm_sale\models\sale_order.py", line 1056, in action_set_usm_produk_bonus
    line.handle_produk_bonus(self.id)
  File "c:\users\enablr02\documents\addons\usm-backend-odoo\usm_sale\models\sale_order.py", line 1288, in handle_produk_bonus
    sol = self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-224>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo14\server\odoo\api.py", line 347, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo14\server\odoo\addons\sale_stock\models\sale_order.py", line 424, in create
    lines.filtered(lambda line: line.state == 'sale')._action_launch_stock_rule()
  File "c:\users\enablr02\documents\addons\usm-backend-odoo\product_bundle_all\models\sale.py", line 61, in _action_launch_stock_rule
    values = line._prepare_procurement_values(group_id=group_id)
  File "c:\users\enablr02\documents\addons\usm-backend-odoo\product_bundle_all\models\sale.py", line 97, in _prepare_procurement_values
    + timedelta(days=self.customer_lead or 0.0) - timedelta(days=self.order_id.company_id.security_lead)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo14\python\lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo14\python\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
Exception
```

This is the function that caused the error :

```
def handle_produk_bonus(self,order_id):
    prod_qty = self.product_uom_qty
    # SaleOrderLine = self.env['sale.order.line']
    print(order_id)
    solines = self.env['sale.order.line'].search([('order_id','=',order_id)])
    prod_bonus = self.env['product.product'].sudo().search([('default_code', '=', self.usm_promo_id.brg_bonus)])
    if not prod_bonus:
        prod_bonus = prod_bonus.create({
            'name': 'Temp product name bonus',
            'default_code': self.usm_promo_id.brg_bonus,
            'type': 'product'
        })
    
    print("here")
    if solines.filtered(lambda x: x.product_id.id == prod_bonus.id):
        return
    values = {
        'order_id': order_id,
        'name': prod_bonus.name,
        'product_uom_qty': prod_qty * self.usm_promo_id.qty_bonus,
        'product_uom': prod_bonus.uom_id.id,
        'price_unit': 0,
        'state':'draft',
        'product_id':prod_bonus.id,
        # 'product_template_id': prod_bonus.product_tmpl_id.id,
        # 'tax_id': [(6, 0, taxes_ids)],
        # 'is_delivery': True,
        'order_line_type': 'bonus'
    }
    sol = self.create(values)
    print(sol)
    return
```

I tried to copy the similar code to create new so line inside sale.order.line model but still no use. Please help me on this matter

Comment: sol = self.line_ids.new(values)

Answer (score 0):

Replace following code

```
sol = self.create(values)
```

to

```
self.env['sale.order.line'].create(values)
```

OR

```
solines.new(values)
```